# AlarmManager not call my service from Android wear app

Tags: java, android, android-service, alarmmanager, wear-os

I create an android wear app and I want to this app create notification some times (In this code I want to call my service every 15 minutes for creating notification)

When I register my service with AlramManager, I can see that task Created in OS (`adb shell dumpsys alarm > dump.txt`) but I can't see the notification or log to prove the service run. I test my service with `startService` and both notification and log worked correctly, So I don't know where is the problem. Here are the codes I use:

MyAlarmService.java

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("From serivce","Service run once");

        // Create notification
        Context context = this;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.NotificationTitle))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_hafez)
            .setContentText("Some text");
        Notification secondPage =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.NotificationTitle))
                    .setContentText("Some text")
                    .build();

        NotificationCompat.WearableExtender extender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();
        extender.addPage(secondPage);
        builder.extend(extender);

        NotificationManagerCompat mgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        int NotificationId = new Random().nextInt(5200);
        mgr.notify(NotificationId, builder.build());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<service android:name=".MyAlarmService" />
...
```

The code that register service in AlarmManager:

```
Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);
```

The content of `dump.txt`

```
Current Alarm Manager state:

...

Batch{91609e num=3 start=7228838 end=7233540 flgs=0x8}:

...

    RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{18a777f type 0 when 1467992333472 org.rashno.mypackagename}

      tag=*walarm*:org.rashno.mypackagename/.MyAlarmService

      type=0 whenElapsed=-6s582ms when=2016-07-08 20:08:53

      window=+11m15s0ms repeatInterval=900000 count=0 flags=0x0

      operation=PendingIntent{397c34c: PendingIntentRecord{de77f95 org.rashno.mypackagename broadcastIntent}}

...

  Alarm Stats:
  ...
    u0a57:org.rashno.mypackagename +9ms running, 1 wakeups:

    +9ms 1 wakes 1 alarms, last -1m33s417ms:

      *walarm*:org.rashno.mypackagename/.MyAlarmService
    ...
  ...
```

Comment: One suggestion (not yet a *solution* ;^): try setting the service to `exported="true"` in your manifest.

Comment: @String I try that but the result is same as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PendingIntent` for a service should be created using `getService`.

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, That's solved my problem. I cannot give you the bounty until next 2 hours.

Comment: When I try repeat my AlarmManager (via `setRepeating` or `set` it again in service) service won't run for second time, Do you know why this happening?

Comment: If the service is already created, then `onCreate` won't be called again. You should either be using `onStartCommand` or switch to using a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Again, THANK YOU SO MUCH